# How do I preserve leading zeros for varchar field

Tags: sql-server, ssms

When saving a number with leading zeros into a string variable or column, leading zeros are truncated.

When I run this query:

```
declare @varchar as nvarchar(50)
set @varchar = 011
print @varchar
```

The result I get is 11.

Is there any way to get 011?

Answer (score 12):

In your code sample, `011` is a numeric, not a string. SQL Server simplifies `011` to `11` it's numeric equivalent, then saves `11` as the string you see in your `@varchar` variable.

If you want the number to be treated as a string, and not a numeric, simply wrap it in quotes. Additionally, since your variable is unicode `nvarchar` and not simply `varchar`, you should prefix the quoted string with an `N`.

This will print the string, preserving leading zeros, using `nvarchar` as you do above:

```
DECLARE @nvarchar AS nvarchar(50);
SET @nvarchar = N'011';
PRINT @nvarchar;
```

But the same holds true with varchar as well:

```
DECLARE @varchar AS varchar(50);
SET @varchar = '011';
PRINT @varchar;
```